# Javascript mouse coordinates and declaring DOCTYPE

Tags: html, doctype, mouse-coordinates

I want to show mouse coordinates in a page and when I don't declare DOCTYPE it works but when I declare DOCTYPE it doesn't! Could you please help me with that? here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>problem</title>
</head>
<body>
    text...
<div id="show"></div>
<script>
    document.body.onmousemove = function(event) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "X: " + window.event.clientX + "<br />" + "Y: " + window.event.clientY;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code above I can get y coordinates with no problem but when I add a doctype it doesn't show y coordinates correctly:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>problem</title>
</head>
<body>
    text...
<div id="show"></div>
<script>
    document.body.onmousemove = function(event) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "X: " + window.event.clientX + "<br />" + "Y: " + window.event.clientY;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

here is my code and it works perfectly now. Thank you all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    text...
    <div id="show"></div>
    <script>
    if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "X: " + window.event.clientX + "<br />" + "Y: " + window.event.clientY;
      });
    } else {
      document.attachEvent("onmousemove", function(event) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "X: " + window.event.clientX + "<br />" + "Y: " + window.event.clientY;
      });

}
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your doctype declaration is invalid. It should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, Actually I always declare doctype the correct way (including in my html file) but here was just a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try do listen mouse event with event Listener, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    text...
    <div id="show"></div>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
        document.body.innerHTML = "X: " + window.event.clientX + "<br />" + "Y: " + window.event.clientY;
    });
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. the problem with this approach is IE8! it doesn't support addEventListener. To solve this problem I used attachEvent (See my post) and now it Works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the correct the declaration of `DOCTYPE` by writing `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of `<DOCTYPE html>`.

Secondly, change your script to:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    document.body.innerHTML = "X: " + event.clientX + "<br />" + "Y: " + event.clientY;
});
```

For the parameters passed in a function can be referred directly, writing `window.event` would be when `event` would be a child of `window` object, in other words a global object.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, Actually I always declare doctype the correct way (including in my html file) but here was just a mistake. by the way, I used "window" because in IE8 event is not recognized if we don't use "window". Thank you so much.